# Overwriting eloquent create() method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to overwrite the `create()` method of an eloquent model to alter some fields (encrypt them) prior to creation.

So in my Model I declare a new method, in which I alter the fields:

```
public static create( array $data)
{
  // for demonstrating purposes I just prepend a string
  $data['fieldName'] = 'xxx'.$data['fieldName'];

  // call the parent' create with the altered data-array
  return parent::create($data)
}
```

But somehow this results in an error:

> Declaration of App\MyModel::create() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create(array $attributes = Array)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter in the method has a default value, so it should be like this:

`public static function create(array $attributes = []) {`

But instead of overwriting the method you could also listen for a create event or use a mutator to set the attribute value and it would be better than overwriting the create method.

Comment: OMG laravel already has the thing I want baked in as a default... Mutators / Accessors it is. Thank you.